# Ubuntu 17 ufw allow ssh only for one ip

Tags: ssh, ufw

When I see logs I see many ssh access tries (type of brute-force attacks) ideally I want to disable ssh for everyone but for my ip address, is that possible?

Or it still will not prevent people trying to login via ssh?

I could try sudo ufw deny ssh but I know I can't use sudo ufw allow ssh from xxx.xx.xx.xxx

I'm pretty noobie with server-side stuff.

Comment: Did you try something like `sudo ufw allow from YOUR_IP proto tcp to any port 22`?

Comment: u mean with ufw deny tcp 22?

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to add an explicit deny rule - since that's the default